# “TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined” When adding a string to an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Here's part of my **client** for a **host**

```
//Displays the room code string, and adds the code to the list of rooms in the server
socket.emit('Add Room', roomCode);
const hostUsername = document.querySelector('#host-username').value;

var obj = {p1: hostUsername, p2: roomCode};
socket.emit('Joined Lobby', obj);
```

Here part of it for a **person joining the host**:

```
const lobbyCode = document.querySelector('#room-code').value;
const playerUsername = document.querySelector('#player-username').value;

    var obj = {p1: playerUsername, p2: lobbyCode};
    socket.emit('Joined Lobby', obj);
```

In my **server** I have the ff declarations:

```
//Stores the details of all online players in a dictionary format
let playerData = {};

//Stores the rooms, and all the players in each room
let roomMap = new Map();
```

In the **server**, This is what happens every time someone connects

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  //Give the socket player details
  const player = {
    name: null,
    room: null,
    host: false
  };

  //Add this player to the dictionary
  playerData[socket.id] = player;
```

This occurs when the socket receives the **Add Room** emmited from the client:

```
  socket.on('Add Room', function (newRoom) {

    //Add the room to the map
    roomMap.set(newRoom, []);

    //Since this player created the room, assign them the host value
    playerData[socket.id].host = true;
  })
```

This occurs when the socket receives the **Joined Lobby** emmited from the client:

```
  socket.on('Joined Lobby', function (values) {

    //Give this player's 'name' variable a value
    playerData[socket.id].name = values.p1;

    //Give this player's 'room' variable a value
    playerData[socket.id].room = values.p2;

    //Put this player in the new room
    socket.join(values.p2);

    let playersList = roomMap.get(values.p2);
    playersList.push(values.p1);

    io.sockets.to(values.p2).emit('Output Players', playersList);
  })
```

When I run my code, the host's username is added to 'playersList' successfully, but when a person is joining the room, it leads to the following error:

> playersList.push(values.p1);
> ^

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: `roomMap.get(values.p2)` is returning `undefined`. You haven't shown that code.

Comment: @Barmar 'values' is declared in the 'joined lobby' socket operation as an argument. I pass the 'obj' declared in the client, which contained 'p1' and 'p2' highlighted at the top of my post

Comment: I guess `values.p2` isn't a room that has been created with `Add Room`.

Comment: @Barmar What if it is the exact value as when the host created the room? The host is able to create the room, and be added to the room players list, but not the player that wants to join it

Comment: If it were then `roomMap.get(values.p2)` would return the array that was created in the `Add Room` oeration.

Comment: Make sure the names match exactly. Watch out for trailing spaces and case differences.

Comment: Use `console.log(roomMap, values.p2)` to confirm all the room names and the room that the player is trying to join.

Comment: @Barmar So what you are saying is that there is nothing when roomMap.get('values.p2') is called. I get it(You clearly stated it at the start, hehe). I'll fix that problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Barmar I managed to identify the error. It involved the data types I was using. Thank you. Now what do I do with this post? Do I delete it, or...?